# How to read keychain item

Tags: objective-c, xcode, keychain, sskeychain

I would like to read a keychain item through Objective-C, I found and read the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/03tasks/tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH205-TP9)

It shows example code, however after properly linking the required frameworks (SystemConfiguration.framework and Security.framework), it is still not clear to me, how I can make it work.

I am also figuring out how to use [SSKeychain](https://github.com/samsoffes/sskeychain) Wrapper, but I get unrecognized selector sent to class upon calling it during runtime:

```
-(IBAction) button:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *keychainAccounts = [[self class] allAccounts];
    NSLog(@"Keychain accounts are: %@", keychainAccounts);
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: could you edit this question to show the lines of code before "`[[self class] allAccounts]`"?  Does "`[self allAccounts]`" work?

Comment: I edited it, thanks for your reply. [self allAccounts] does not work, because it is a class method from SSKeychain. It must have something to do with proper class recognition, because I get "+[PreferencesController allAccounts]: unrecognized selector sent to class" Where + means it is a class and I wonder whether SSKeychain shouldn't appear before allAccounts instead.